# standard error & standard deviation (Poisson counts)

Tags: standard-deviation, poisson-distribution, standard-error, count-data, poisson-process

I observe **25 events** over a period of **50 seconds**. I assume that the events are generated by an underlying Poisson process.

1. What is the **standard deviation** of the count?
2. What is the **standard error** of the count?

   ---

Please note that I understand the concept of a standard error for a sample mean, but am having difficulty understanding the concept of a standard error for an observed count (i.e., the observation of 25 counts is just **one observation**).

My understanding of standard error is thus: given an infinite population with a known mean ($\mu$) and known standard deviation ($\sigma$), then $\sim 68$% of random samples will have $\bar{x}$ within $\pm 1 \times$ standard error of the true mean $\mu$. The standard deviation of the sample is the best estimate of $\sigma$. So standard error on the sample mean is given by $SE_\bar{x}=s/\sqrt{n}$ - intuitively, I can see why it's proportional to $\sigma$ and inversely proportional to $n$, but my knowledge goes no further (e.g., why $\sqrt{n}$, why not proportional to $\sigma^2$, etc).

Comment: What, then, is your understanding of a standard error of the mean?  If it's related to the concept of variation under repeated sampling, then contemplate what the outcome of your count would be under repeated sampling.  If variation under repeated sampling is not part of your understanding, then it would be best for you to edit this post to include a statement of what your understanding is.

Comment: I think a good way to approach this question (assuming independence) is that the seconds are an exposure. This allows you to estimate the mean and variance of the Poisson process. The sum of 50 Poissons is also a Poisson, which allows you to get the mean and standard deviation of the count, which will pin down the standard error.

Comment: @whuber - have edited as per suggestion. Given my single observation, my best estimate is that further 50-second observations will yield 25 events (on average). And given that the events are generated by a Poisson process, the best estimate for the standard deviation for each 50-second interval will be $s=\sqrt{25}$. Given that I have taken a single observation ($n=1$), I think the standard error should be $SE = s / \sqrt{n} = \sqrt{25} / \sqrt{1}$. So my conclusion is that standard error and standard deviation are the same. But I feel like I've totally misunderstood somewhere along the lines.

Comment: @Dimitriy - not sure I follow - are you saying I can treat this as 50 samples of a Poisson process parameterised by $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda=0.5)$?

Comment: @Ben Yes, that is what I had in mind.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov - in that case, would the standard error be $\sqrt{0.5}/\sqrt{50} = 0.1$, where the 50 refers to the number of 1-second samples? But then $\lambda$ is fixed (from that one experiment) and the choice of "exposure" seems arbitrary - if I choose 25-second intervals, then the standard error becomes $\sqrt{0.5}/\sqrt{2} = 0.5$. Indeed, I could choose the number of samples based on minutes, hours, lunar cycles, etc. What does sample size signify in the context of counts?

Comment: The SE is correct. The count is proportional to exposure, so if you keep the rate fixed and shorten the exposure, you get a smaller count, with a smaller standard deviation. Think of the typical Poisson horse kick process for the Prussian army. If you wait longer or you conscript more men, the number of events gets larger.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov - can you clarify which SE is correct? I gave two answers. Specifically, it would really help me if you could explain why the denominator of  $SE=\sqrt{0.5}/\sqrt{50}$ is 50 (i.e., seconds) and not, e.g., minutes ($5/6$) which is exactly the same duration, but expressed in different units.

Comment: @Ben The SE= 0.1 was right for the question as written. The per minute version would be $\sqrt(\frac{30}{5/6})$ since the expected number of events would increase since you changed to per minute. It is possible that I am not understanding what you are asking, but then it is better to alter your question (or ask a new one) rather than hashing it out in the comments.